# Find a p tag under a div with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have html markup like below:

```
<div class="inline-error-content">
  <p>Invalid number.</p>
</div>
```

It is a validation tag rendered when letters are typed into the Phone Number field on the screen.  I am writing a Selenium regression test to verify that this works - however, I am unsure how to get the p tag when it is rendered with no id or class name.  I don't really want to just find all p tags rendered by XPath as there would be multiple returned.

I was trying the code below

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Name("telephoneNumber")).SendKeys("abc");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
var result = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'inline-error-content')]"));
```

The `.Text` on the result is an empty string

Comment: What is your validation? Are you trying to ensure that the HTML above doesn't exist or ? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the p tag "Invalid number." text? If so, you could use a straight forward XPath as follows:

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'inline-error-content')]/p[text()='Invalid number'])
```

You could even make it scan all p tags and just find the single record considering there are no p nodes with the Invalid number text.

```
By.XPath("//p[text()='Invalid number'])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to check text of `<p>`, then choose it with your xpath:

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'inline-error-content')]/p")
```

Also, sleeping in the test is generally a bad idea. Use [Wait and Expected Condition](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) instead:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'inline-error-content')]/p")));
```

Comment: When I debug this I am seeing Tag name and hover over result var I see tag name as "p" but the text string in still empty "".  I was expecting it to be "Invalid number." That is then what i am driving my Assert.AreEqual from

Comment: could be 3 possible causes: 1. that xpath matches multiple locations (so see if any other elements have `contains(@class, 'inline-error-content')` condition met; 2. not waiting long enough (so set maybe `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` to avoid that issue for now); 3. tag itself or one of its parents are not set to visible, in which case selenium won't return anything. So check that as well: `myDynamicElement.Displayed && myDynamicElement.Enabled`

Comment: cheers - will take a look at those 3 options.  what would be the best solution if it is cause 1